# Cone in higher dimensions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-cone

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open convex set of $R^{n}$, $u \in C^{0}(\bar{\Omega})$ a convex function, and $v$ a convex function whose graph is the upside down cone with vertex $(x_{0},u(x_{0}))$ and base $\Omega$.

I don't understand two properties of the function $v$. I think I lack some obious facts about $v$.

Can you show me, please, how to prove those two properties to help me to understand ?

1) Forall $x \in \Omega$, $u(x) \le v(x)$

2) Suppose forall $x \in \Omega, v(x) \ge v(x_{1}) + \langle p, x-x_{1} \rangle $ .
If $x_{0} \ne x_{1}$ then $v(x_{1}) = v(x_{0}) + \langle p, x_{1}-x_{0} \rangle $

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: You didn't give us enough information to conclude (1). Do you know the inequality holds on the boundary of $\Omega$?

Comment: I tell myself... Maybe $v(x) = u(x_{0}) + a|x-x_{0}|$. What do you about it ?

Comment: Oh yeah excuse me, $v = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$ as $u$